# Open chrome app (not extension) inside tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

So The problem is the following.

I need to create chromeApp (the abilities of chrome app)
But For better UX, I would like it to be open in a tab.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Extensions can do this. Chrome Apps can not.

If you create a Chrome App and attempt to open any url in a tab window, it will fail. This behavior is restricted. I believe this is done to make sure that Packaged Apps only operate in App windows to give the user that native feel.

1) Create an *extension* instead of an *app*.
2) Use **chrome.app.windows.create** to create a window and point it to the url of your document. You can specify a height/width or allow the user to resize the window.

Complete information on **chrome.app.windows.create** is here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just use `open(url)` in the background script.